# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are http

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I write a SL+WCF UserName Password authorization Demo according to the Link below.But I can't get rid of it.

My Web.config:

http://blogs.infosupport.com/silverlight-3-securing-your-wcf-service-with-a-custom-username-and-password-authentication-mechanism/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        </system.web>

        <system.serviceModel>



      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      <services>
        <service name="Sample.Web.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >

          <host>
             <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://localhost"/>
             </baseAddresses>
          </host>

          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="Sample.Web.IService">
            <identity>
              <

    dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
              </endpoint>
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

            </service>
          </services>

          <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="test">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security>
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
          </bindings>

          <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                   <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                       customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Sample.Web.MyValidator, Sample.Web"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
              </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
          </behaviors>

        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because you haven't configured IIS on your machine to support HTTPS for the website under which this application is hosted. WCF requires a Secure HTTP connection when you use this specified security option. You need to map a service certificate on IIS for the website in question.

Comment: Either configure SSL on IIS OR (remove `https` & security mode must not be transport in that case)

Comment: Thanks!!! As I use VS2010 to debug, how can I configure my project in vs2010 to suppert https?

Comment: @user3566983: Scott Hanselman was nice enough to write up a guide on how to make this happen: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx